# Gemfire '@type' not working

Tags: gemfire

I'm trying to use gemfire rest api with gemfire native client.
What I have working:

1. crud for my object via native client
2. retrieve and delete of the same object via rest api

When I try to perform the create/update via rest api with `@type` and then try to get it via gemfire native client I get

> "com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl cannot be cast to...

I checked Docs:
https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/rest_apps/rest_prereqs.html
and:

> To achieve interoperability between GemFire Java clients (or GemFire native clients) and REST clients, the following rules must be followed:
>
> 1. All GemFire Java and native client classes operating on data also accessed by the REST interface must be PDX serialized, either via PDX autoserialization or by implementing PdxSerializable.
> 2. GemFire Java clients and native clients can retrieve REST-enabled data either as a PdxInstance or as an actual object by using the PdxInstance.getObject method. If you use the latter method, you must first declare the object type (@type) in your POST or PUT request payload when creating the object in REST; and secondly, the Java client must have the actual domain class in its CLASSPATH.

I see I have PDX autoserialization working in my case. So I execute create/update request. But `@type` isn't handled as I expected.

I have gemfire version 8.2.0

My only solution is to implement `PdxSerializable` ?

A basic example of what I do:

My object Person has fields: id, name. It is located at `com.package`.

1. I save my object with gemfire native client.
2. I execute Http `PUT` request `/gemfire-api/v1/{region}/{key}` with payload:
   `'{ "@type":"com.package.Person", "id":"someId", "name":"name" }'`
3. I try to retrieve it with HTTP GET - successfully
4. I try to retrieve it with gemfire native client and cast it to Person object with `getObject()` - I have an error

Comment: could you please post your put request with json?

Comment: updated with example

Comment: It actually sounds like a version 7 library behavior. Can’t really think of a reason why it should happen. Might help to try look into decompiled/source code of getObject. In the version 8 of java Gemfire, it has a check on @type field and cast accordingly.

Comment: Could you please include the code you are using to retrieve the object  and also the whole stack trace ?